# Uploading to BlobStore in Google App Engine from a Command Line Java Application

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, command-line, blobstore

Here is my server side code for my blobstore uploading command line application:

```
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UploadServlet.class.getName());

    private final BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        final Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = bs.getUploadedBlobs(request);
        final BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("blob");

        if (blobKey == null)
        {
            log.severe("BlobKey was null!");
            response.sendRedirect("/error.html");
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/image?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates the custom single use blobstore URL's that are needed to upload to the blobstore programmatically. */
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        final String uploadURL = bs.createUploadUrl("/upload");
        final PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        pw.write(uploadURL);
    }
}
```

I have gotten the following code to work against my local development mode server, without the authentication code so I know the `multipart/form` code is working fine, with the authentication code, it fails with:

```
    r = opener.open(request)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found
```

Moved from Java to Python for the command line client:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://myapp.appspot.com/upload')
bloburl = f.read(1024)
print bloburl
print

image = file('120.jpg', 'r')
form = MultiPartForm()
form.add_file('blob', 'blob', image, 'image/jpeg')

request = urllib2.Request(bloburl)
body = str(form)
request.add_header('Content-type', form.get_content_type())
request.add_header('Content-length', len(body))
request.add_data(body)

opener = auth.get_auth_opener('myapp', 'username', 'password')
r = opener.open(request)
data = r.read()
print data
```

I just want a simple command line tool that takes a file and posts it to the BlobStore. I can't find a single **COMPLETE** example anywhere on the internet. There are lots of examples that do all the work on GAE, but none that are command line clients that do the `POST` of the `FORM` from a separate client.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the output of your client-side code to verify it's including the correct headers?

Comment: where do I get information on what the correct headers should be?

Comment: I want this too. I'm pretty sure the POST does not have any specific requirements (in terms of headers) because it can be made by a normal browser form upload; it just needs to have a URL created by `BlobstoreService.createUploadURL`. The problem as I see it is that your app will presumably need a user to log in to perform uploads, so the command-line app will need to get a Google cookie.

Answer (score 1):

[Since version 1.4.3 There is an experimental API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to write directly to the blobstore.
It saves you from the need to upload to the blobstore using POSTs.